# Access AnyHashable by index

Tags: swift, macos, swift3

I'm new to Swift and I can't find out how I can access by index a variable of type `[AnyHashable : Any]`

To be more specific, I want to access by index the `allHeaderFields` variable of an `HTTPURLResponse` instance. I expected something like the following to work but it doesn't:

```
httpResponse.allHeaderFields[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift 3, `[AnyHashable: Any]` is just a default Dictionary type imported from `NSDictionary`. You can access its contents like a normal Dictionary:

```
if let contentType = httpResponse.allHeaderFields["Content-Type"] as? String {
    print(contentType)
}
```

Or:

```
for (key, value) in httpResponse.allHeaderFields {
    print(key, value)
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to display all headers in a NSTableView. The method to be overridden in order to display a column provides me with the row number. I can't know the header names a priori.

Comment: @LazarusLazaridis, you can easily convert Swift Dictionary into Array using `map`. `let headerArray = httpResponse.allHeaderFields.map{$0}`. Or you can construct your own Array modifying my second code snippet.

Comment: That's what I do at the moment, I wanted to make sure I'm not doing it wrong cause I'm like 2 days new to swift ;). Thanks for the help.

Comment: @LazarusLazaridis, in some cases (someone says this "some" should be "many"), Swift does not give us a super-easy way. Good luck for you and for your app.